# Change the default highlight color of text in word document with office js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

How to change the default text highlight color from gray to any other color with office js in a word document?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code:

```
 // Gets the current selection and changes the font color to red.
      await Word.run(async (context) => {
        let suggestedPosition = context.document.getSelection();
        suggestedPosition.load('font');
        await context.sync();
        suggestedPosition.font.color = 'Red';
        suggestedPosition.track();
        await context.sync();
      });
```

or

```
// Change the font color
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
await Word.run(async (context) => {

    // Create a range proxy object for the current selection.
    const selection = context.document.getSelection();

    // Queue a command to change the font color of the current selection.
    selection.font.color = 'blue';

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    await context.sync();
    console.log('The font color of the selection has been changed.');
});
```

See the [Word.Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.font?view=word-js-preview) class for available properties and methods.